# Hazelcast Client Only Configuration

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is it possible to create a client only hazelcast node? We have hazelcast embedded in our Java Applications and they use a common hazelcast.xml. This works fine, however when one of our JVM's is distressed, it causes the other clustered JVM's to slow down and have issues. I want to run a hazelcast cluster outside of our application stack and update the common hazelcast.xml to point to the external cluster. I have tried various config options but the application JVM's always want to start a listener and become members. I realize I maybe asking for something that defeats the purpose of hazelcast, however I thought it may be possible to configure an instance to be a client only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your application to use Hazelcast client instances, but it requires a code change.
Instead of

```java
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

you'll need to initialize your instance by requesting a client one:

```java
HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
```

Another option is to keep the code unchanged and configure your embedded members to be "lite" ones. So they don't own any partition (they don't store cluster data).

```xml
<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
           http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-4.0.xsd">
    <!--
        ===== HAZELCAST LITE MEMBER CONFIGURATION =====

        Configuration element's name is <lite-member>. When you want to use a Hazelcast member as a lite member,
        set this element's "enabled" attribute to true in that member's XML configuration. Lite members do not store
        data and are used mainly to execute tasks and register listeners. They do not have partitions.
    -->
    <lite-member enabled="true"/>
</hazelcast>
```